# Converting Pandas DataFrame to spatially enabled DataFrame geometry removes geometry In some cases

Tags: arcgis-pro, pandas, arcgis-python-api, spatially-enabled-dataframe

I want to convert my Pandas DataFrame with a WKT geometry column to a Spatially Enabled DataFrame (SEDF) and then into a featureclass in a geodatabase; however, sometimes the geometry column in the resulting SEDF is blank.  Here is an example:

This DF to SEDF conversion works just fine.

```
from arcgis.features import GeoAccessor
df = pd.DataFrame(['POLYGON ((-122.4879908428375 37.8580879209098, -122.48752841647929 37.8578624638935, -122.48727791959379 37.85818273662985, -122.487740345952 37.858408193646149, -122.4879908428375 37.8580879209098))'], columns = ['SHAPE'])
    sedf = GeoAccessor.from_df(
        df=df,
        sr=4326,
        geometry_column= 'SHAPE', )
```

This DF to SEDF conversion appears to delete the geometries in the SHAPE column:

```
from arcgis.features import GeoAccessor
df = pd.DataFrame(['POLYGON ((-79.841542412627334 40.511379203842651, -79.841545978234777 40.511381914693381, -79.84155175157241 40.511385469109257, -79.841557981970013 40.511388545242923, -79.841564601166084 40.5113911093916, -79.841571536639307 40.511393133461922, -79.841578712403177 40.511394595277778, -79.84158604983854 40.5113954788232, -79.8415934685549 40.511395774417863, -79.841600887271269 40.5113954788232, -79.841608224706633 40.511394595277778, -79.8416154004705 40.511393133461922, -79.841622335943725 40.5113911093916, -79.8416289551398 40.511388545242923, -79.8416351855374 40.511385469109257, -79.841640958875033 40.511381914693381, -79.841646211898762 40.5113779209382, -79.8416508870554 40.511373531600142, -79.841654933122911 40.511368794769687, -79.841658305771759 40.511363762344573, -79.841660968050491 40.511358489461088, -79.84166289079063 40.511353033890053, -79.84166405292622 40.511347455403843, -79.841664441724674 40.511341815121511, -79.84166405292622 40.511336174839187, -79.84166289079063 40.51133059635297, -79.841660968050491 40.511325140781928, -79.841658305771759 40.51131986789845, -79.841654933122911 40.511314835473343, -79.8416508870554 40.511310098642888, -79.841646211898762 40.511305709304821, -79.841640958875033 40.511301715549642, -79.8416351855374 40.511298161133759, -79.8416289551398 40.5112950850001, -79.841622335943725 40.511292520851427, -79.8416154004705 40.5112904967811, -79.841608224706633 40.511289034965237, -79.841600887271269 40.511288151419834, -79.8415934685549 40.511287855825159, -79.84158604983854 40.511288151419834, -79.841578712403177 40.511289034965237, -79.841571536639307 40.5112904967811, -79.841564601166084 40.511292520851427, -79.841557981970013 40.5112950850001, -79.84155175157241 40.511298161133759, -79.841545978234777 40.511301715549642, -79.841540725211047 40.511305709304821, -79.841536050054415 40.511310098642888, -79.8415320039869 40.511314835473343, -79.841528631338051 40.51131986789845, -79.841525969059319 40.511325140781928, -79.841525845748663 40.511325490662813, -79.841078013264578 40.51121738182654, -79.84106219300962 40.511264926460342, -79.84105393100468 40.511313564959153, -79.8410533447901 40.511362605362, -79.841060442705725 40.5114113499902, -79.841075123772256 40.511459105372943, -79.841097179127914 40.511505192113013, -79.841126294999739 40.51154895455231, -79.841162057167566 40.511589770099711, -79.841203956856987 40.511627058088308, -79.841542412627334 40.511379203842651))'], columns = ['SHAPE'])
sedf = GeoAccessor.from_df(
    df=df,
    sr=4326,
    geometry_column= 'SHAPE', )
```

Is there a way to get a valid SEDF in this scenario?  I've checked the WKT geometry with Shapely's .is_valid method and it's valid.  Alternatively, is there a way to get from WKT to a geodatabase without the SEDF intermediary?

I'm using ArcGIS version 1.9.1 and ArcPy 2.9.  I recently updated my ArcGIS Pro to v2.9.  I did not have this issue with 2.8 and its associated packages.

Answer (score 0):

I found a messy workaround using Shapely to export to a shapefile then using ArcPy to move the shapefile into my desired geodatabase. If anyone has an ArcGIS solution I'd love to see it.

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import shapely.wkt
import arcpy

wkt_poly = 'POLYGON ((-79.841542412627334 40.511379203842651, -79.841545978234777 40.511381914693381, -79.84155175157241 40.511385469109257, -79.841557981970013 40.511388545242923, -79.841564601166084 40.5113911093916, -79.841571536639307 40.511393133461922, -79.841578712403177 40.511394595277778, -79.84158604983854 40.5113954788232, -79.8415934685549 40.511395774417863, -79.841600887271269 40.5113954788232, -79.841608224706633 40.511394595277778, -79.8416154004705 40.511393133461922, -79.841622335943725 40.5113911093916, -79.8416289551398 40.511388545242923, -79.8416351855374 40.511385469109257, -79.841640958875033 40.511381914693381, -79.841646211898762 40.5113779209382, -79.8416508870554 40.511373531600142, -79.841654933122911 40.511368794769687, -79.841658305771759 40.511363762344573, -79.841660968050491 40.511358489461088, -79.84166289079063 40.511353033890053, -79.84166405292622 40.511347455403843, -79.841664441724674 40.511341815121511, -79.84166405292622 40.511336174839187, -79.84166289079063 40.51133059635297, -79.841660968050491 40.511325140781928, -79.841658305771759 40.51131986789845, -79.841654933122911 40.511314835473343, -79.8416508870554 40.511310098642888, -79.841646211898762 40.511305709304821, -79.841640958875033 40.511301715549642, -79.8416351855374 40.511298161133759, -79.8416289551398 40.5112950850001, -79.841622335943725 40.511292520851427, -79.8416154004705 40.5112904967811, -79.841608224706633 40.511289034965237, -79.841600887271269 40.511288151419834, -79.8415934685549 40.511287855825159, -79.84158604983854 40.511288151419834, -79.841578712403177 40.511289034965237, -79.841571536639307 40.5112904967811, -79.841564601166084 40.511292520851427, -79.841557981970013 40.5112950850001, -79.84155175157241 40.511298161133759, -79.841545978234777 40.511301715549642, -79.841540725211047 40.511305709304821, -79.841536050054415 40.511310098642888, -79.8415320039869 40.511314835473343, -79.841528631338051 40.51131986789845, -79.841525969059319 40.511325140781928, -79.841525845748663 40.511325490662813, -79.841078013264578 40.51121738182654, -79.84106219300962 40.511264926460342, -79.84105393100468 40.511313564959153, -79.8410533447901 40.511362605362, -79.841060442705725 40.5114113499902, -79.841075123772256 40.511459105372943, -79.841097179127914 40.511505192113013, -79.841126294999739 40.51154895455231, -79.841162057167566 40.511589770099711, -79.841203956856987 40.511627058088308, -79.841542412627334 40.511379203842651))'

# Here's an example Shapely geometry
poly = shapely.wkt.loads(wkt_poly)
sr = osr.SpatialReference()
sr.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

# Now convert it to a shapefile with OGR    
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('Esri Shapefile')
ds = driver.CreateDataSource('temp_data\\my.shp')
layer = ds.CreateLayer('', sr, ogr.wkbPolygon)
# Add one attribute
layer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn('id', ogr.OFTInteger))
defn = layer.GetLayerDefn()

# Create a new feature (attribute and geometry)
feat = ogr.Feature(defn)
feat.SetField('id', 123)

# Make a geometry, from Shapely object
geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(poly.wkb)
feat.SetGeometry(geom)

layer.CreateFeature(feat)
feat = geom = None  # destroy these

# Save and close everything
ds = layer = feat = geom = None
 
# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = '<workspace_dir>'
 
# Set local variables
in_features = ['my.shp']
out_location = '<gdb_dir>'
 
# Execute FeatureClassToGeodatabase
arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(in_features, out_location)
```